# window.scrollBy in conflict with jjmslideshow? Page doesn't scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I implemented this simple script to make a "smooth scroll" effect when the target link is clicked:

```
 (function() {

'use strict';

// Feature Test
if ( 'querySelector' in document && 'addEventListener' in window && Array.prototype.forEach ) {

    // Function to animate the scroll
    var smoothScroll = function (anchor, duration) {

        // Calculate how far and how fast to scroll
        var startLocation = window.pageYOffset;
        var endLocation = anchor.offsetTop;
        var distance = endLocation - startLocation;
        var increments = distance/(duration/16);
        var stopAnimation;

        // Scroll the page by an increment, and check if it's time to stop
        var animateScroll = function () {
            window.scrollBy(0, increments);
            stopAnimation();
        };

        /....Other code irrilevant to the question./

                 Interval(animateScroll, 16);

    };

    // Define smooth scroll links
    var scrollToggle = document.querySelectorAll('.scroll');

    // For each smooth scroll link
    [].forEach.call(scrollToggle, function (toggle) {

        // When the smooth scroll link is clicked
        toggle.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

            // Prevent the default link behavior
            e.preventDefault();

            // Get anchor link and calculate distance from the top
            var dataID = toggle.getAttribute('href');
            var dataTarget = document.querySelector(dataID);
            var dataSpeed = toggle.getAttribute('data-speed');

            // If the anchor exists
            if (dataTarget) {
                // Scroll to the anchor
                smoothScroll(dataTarget, dataSpeed || 500);
            }

        }, false);

    });

}
```

So when i click on a link signed with the class .scroll the page slowly scroll down to the target anchor.
In a semi-blank page everything works fine but after i added a slideshow made with jmpress plugin the smooth scroll stopped to work.
Does anyone knows jmpress plugin enough to understand why this are in conflict?

Excuse me for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of `jmpress plugin` but as you mentioned that it conflicts with other jquery. If so then wrap your function like this:

```
(function($){

......
.......

})(jQuery);
```

Or

you can use [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) method.